# Getting error passing char array pointer into a function in C

Tags: visual-c++

Getting error passing char array pointer into a function in C. 
I am using VC++ editor to build this.

error C3861: 'DecodeData': identifier not found

Decoder.h

```
int DecodeAudioBytes();

int DecodeData(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

Decoder.c

```
int DecodeAudioBytes()
{
char* argv[] = { "test", "test1" };

return DecodeData(2, argv);

}
int DecodeData( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   char      speechOutFileName[ 150 ], bitInFileName[ 150 ];

   int args = 0;
   strcpy( bitInFileName, argv[ args ] );
   args++;
   strcpy( speechOutFileName, argv[ args ] );
   args++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the definition of `DecodeData` before `DecodeAudioBytes`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Forhad.

You can also put only the declaration before:

```
static int DecodeData(int argc, char* argv[])

int DecodeAudioBytes()
{
    char* argv[] = { "test", "test1" };

    return DecodeData(2, argv);

}
int DecodeData( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
}
```

When the compiler finds the identifier `DecodeData` knows nothing about it yet, as it is declared afterwards.

Comment: Additionally to what Forhad proposes, you should also `#include <string.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved. I forgot to include header file in the "C" file.

Thanks!